# How to run dnx xunit test from the commandline for a different framework?

Tags: command-line, frameworks, clr, dnx, xunit

The `project.json` file:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "xunit": "2.1.0",
        "xunit.runner.dnx": "2.1.0-rc1-build204"
    },

    "commands": {
        "test": "xunit.runner.dnx"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx452": {
        },

        "dnxcore50": {
        }
    }
}
```

`

In case I've defined multiple frameworks in the project.json, how to start xunit from the command-line for a specific framework?

`dnx --framework dnxcore50 -p test/Hello.Test test` does not seem to take the **dnxcore50** as the running framework, it's still listed as `xUnit.net DNX Runner (32-bit DNX 4.5.2)`?

In Visual Studio 2015, all works fine, I can switch from to `CLR Type (.NET Framework)` to `CLR Type (.NET Core)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a bit late but you don't have to do anything. If you have multiple frameworks in your test project's project.json file `dotnet test` command will run the test for all the frameworks.